# Intersection points of two polynomials

Tags: polynomials, derivatives

How to prove that two distinct polynomial functions of degree m and n, respectively,the graphs intersect in at most $max(m,n)$ points.

Comment: Hint : if P and $Q$ are the polynomial consider the polynomial $P-Q$ and its roots.
(or consider @Hagen von Eitzen answer ^^)

Comment: If the restriction to polynomial *functions* is relaxed and the intersections of two polynomial *curves* is considered, there can be $mn$ points of intersection for curves of degree $m$ and $n$.  E.g. two quadratic curves (conics) may intersect in up to four points.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $p(X),q(X)$ be polynomials of degrees $\deg p=m, \deg q=n$.
Then the difference $r(X)=p(X)-q(X)$ is a polynomial of degree **at most** $\max\{m,n\}$ (in fact $\deg r=\max\{m,n\}$ if $m\ne n$ or the leading coefficients differ). If $p=q$, the difference turns out to be the zero polynomial and hence the polynomials agree *everywhere* (of course), but that case is excluded.
Since $p\ne q$, we have $r\ne0$ and the points of intersection are the roots of $r(X)$, hence there are **at most** $\deg r$ many.

Comment: Any deeper proof?

Comment: Fundamental Theorem of Algebra @pourjour.

Comment: So if supposed two polynomials $P(x)=x^2$ and $Q(x)=x^3$
r(x) would be $r(x)=x^3-x^2$ and the fact that this polynomial has two roots $0,1$ means that those two polynomials intersect in $0,P(0)$ and $1, P(1)$.
in the other hand I have $max(3,2)=3$ that mean I must found 3 points of intersections, isn't that true?

Comment: @pourjour at most 3 points, not exactly 3 points.

Comment: @pourjour any point $x_i$ of intersection gives rise to a linear factor $X-x_i$ of $r(X)$. Multiplying too many factors would result in too high a degree.

Comment: one should count with multiplicity, right. So x^3-x^2= (x-0)^2 (x-1) has multiplicity 2 at 0, and 1 at 1.