# How many times can these two polynomial intersect with each other?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra

Suppose $g(x)=a_1x+a_2x^2+...+a_kx^k$ and $f(x)=b_jx^j$ where $a_1,a_2...a_k>0$ , $j\in \{1,2.....,k-1\}$, $b_j >0$ and $x\geq0$.

Intuitively, I think they can have at most two intersections. Is that correct?

Well, the answer is it has two positive roots by Descartes' rule of signs. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you want the count of intersections given specific k and specific j or the number of intersections for a specific k for any j? (I understand that j is restricted).

Comment: What can you say about the solutions of $g(x) = f(x)$?

Comment: You may also want to check:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469050/intersection-points-of-two-polynomials and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity

Comment: for $g(x)=\left(x-1\right)\left(x-2\right)\left(x-.5\right)\left(x-4\right)\left(x-4.5\right)$ and $f(x)=0.12$ there are 5 intersections. See:https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ja6oluul0s

Comment: There from 0 to larger of (k,j)

Comment: @NoChance There are some restrictions that $a_1,a_2....a_k$ are greater than zero. In your example, some coefficients are negative.

Comment: @Lucas I'm not sure. I just know both g(x) and f(x) are strictly increasing function.

Comment: @Moti There are some differences between this problem and the general Polynomials. Here all coefficients are positive and the domain is $x \geq 0$

Comment: By [Descartes' rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes'_rule_of_signs#Positive_roots), at most $2$ intersections for $x \color{red}{>} 0$.

Comment: @achillehui Thanks! You're right!

Comment: @Kaka At most 2 positive + another at (0,0), so at most 3 non-negative.

Comment: @bjorn93 Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

The general answer to this question is given by [Bezout's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_theorem). It states that two polynomials of degree $n$ and $m$ have precisely $n\cdot m$ intersection points provided that you

1. are over an algebraically closed field
2. count including multiplicities
3. also count possible intersections at infinity.

This is overkill for your situation but when applied to polynomials over the reals it still means you can have **at most** $m\cdot n$ intersections. One can find examples where you actually have that many real intersections.